# How should I get derivatives from scipy RBFInterpolator? (simply, as with bisplev)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

Question about [scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator.html#scipy-interpolate-rbfinterpolator)

I've found RBF gives much smoother 2D interpolation results than B-Splines via [scipy.interpolate.bisplref](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html#scipy-interpolate-bisplrep) with my particular data, but I need to take derivatives of what I get. When I evaluate the B-Splines using [scipy.interpolate.bisplev](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplev.html#scipy-interpolate-bisplev), I can specify dx and dy to get any order of derivative in each dimention. Is there a similar sort of thing for RBFInterpolator that I'm just not seeing in the documentation? Or should I just take the gradient of the evaluated spline w/ numpy.gradient?

Answer (score 0):

don't know about RBFInterpolator, but to take derivatives you can use [scipy.misc.derivative](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/scipy-derivative#google_vignette) (the second half of the linked page - just scroll it down to see example)

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: corrected, but `scipy v1.10.0 (released Jan 3, 2023) has deprecated scipy.misc.derivative`